# $I->see() always fails codeception

Tags: php, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm new to Codeception, and have tried to set up a really basic acceptance test. I am running it with PhantomJS.

I'm trying to just detect some text on the page, and for some reason, it never passes. My index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>


 </body>
</html>
```

And my test file, HelloCept. php is:

```
<?php 
 $I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
 $I->amOnPage('index.html');
 $I->see('Hello World');
```

The `$I->amOnPage` DOES pass. Also, if I try $I->am('user'), that passes, as well-- the issue just seems to be detecting actual elements on the page!

In case it helps, my acceptance.suite.yml file is:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
 modules:
enabled:
- WebDriver:
         url: 'http://localhost:4444/'            
         browser: phantomjs
```

And in my browser, I run:

http://127.0.0.1:4444/index.html

I saw on the GitHub page people had similar issues, but it seemed as though the issue had been resolved. However, I just can't get this simple test to pass. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: try "/index.html" ?

Comment: It still fails. If I get rid of  $I->see('Hello World'); and just have $I->amOnPage('index.html');, that passes, so I don't think it's an issue with the page.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well. I have some tests that were working fine a couple of months ago, and now they are all failing on the "See" tests.

Comment: What seems to be happening, is that you aren't connecting to the page. In other words, Phantom is going SOMEWHERE, but your web server isn't serving it properly. Try: open a browser and go to "index.html" & "http://localhost:4444/index.html" & "/" then add "http://" to each of those and report. What kind of server are you using [OS etc.]. Can you see the page in a browser? Change the YML to "'http://localhost/'. Add the --html flag when you run the test and see what it says. Set -vvv and see what it says. It's something in your configuation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an id to the element and check if you see that. Not sure though :)

Comment: I don't think that is what it is. see() should just find the text in the DOM anywhere. Or visiable rather.

Answer (score 0):

Chane the YML to:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
 modules:
enabled:
- WebDriver:
         url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/index.html'            
         browser: phantomjs
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this issue as well. I have some tests that were working fine a couple of months ago, and now they are all failing on the "See" tests.

I discovered a couple things that may help:

1) I added a minification step to my HTML compiler to remove unnecessary white space, and this seems to break codeception's ability to parse the page. So if your HTML is minified, try the tests on an unminified version.

2) Try wrapping your tests in a class as described at http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage. This seems to have worked for me.

```
<?php

class FirstCest
{
    public function frontpageWorks(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('index.html');
        $I->see('Hello World');
    }
}
```